# Safari-style back button

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I've not found on stackoverflow a modern solution how to make a Safari-style back button for `UIBarButtonItem`. Is there a simple and elegant way to implement a back button as it is in Safari?

[image: Safari toolbar screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS13 and above, you can use the built-in `SF Symbols` library provided by Apple.

The `chevron.left` image is used for the Safari back button.

```
let chevronLeft = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: chevronLeft, style: .plain, target: webView, action: #selector(webView!.goBack))
```

These icons also come in nine weights from ultralight to black, which can be applied like this.

```
let chevronLeft = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .thin))
```

More information is available from Apple here: [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/)

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution. The best way is to find back button image on web and use this code:

```
    let backIcon = UIImage(named: "backIcon")
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backIcon, style: .plain, target: webView, action: #selector(webView!.goBack))
```

For example:

[image]
[image]
[image]